# Android/WearOS Program Structure

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os

I am new to Android development and wanted some guidance. I am building a Mobile + WearOS app. I have a shared project, which I expect to be for the objects each device will manipulate. I have SQLlite utilities, those should be in a directory of the mobile app under the java directory. Does all that sound right from a structure standpoint? I expect I will have cloud utilities as well which will be a different directory under the mobile app java directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your problem is: How to share codes between mobile and wear module.

You need to create an `AndroidLibrary` Module through `File - New - New Module`. After that 
 add it as a dependency to your mobile and wear module. Just in `build.gradle` (mobile's and wear's) add `implementation project(':{your_module_name}')` in `dependencies` section.

Now you can move all your codes that you want to share to the new lib moudule, then both mobile and wear mudule can ues them.